# I do not get to pass props through mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to pass an action to my component through mapDispatchToPropsm but it keeps telling me the action is not a function. I have also tried to pass the doGoogleLoginAction object directly to the connect, but it is also not working. I guess there is a problem in the action itself, but I do not get to see what it is. The problem triggers when I click on the iniciar button in the LoginPage.js

here is the userReducer.js:

```
//PATRON DE DISEÑO REDUX DUCK
import { loginWithGoogle } from "../firebase";

const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  fetching: false
};

//---CONSTANTS----
const LOGIN = "LOGIN";
const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
const LOGIN_ERROR = "LOGIN_ERROR";

//---REDUCERS---
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case "LOGIN_ERROR":
      return { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, fetching: false, ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
} //el reducer esta siempre escuchando hasta que hagas una accion que coincida con las definidas

//---ACTIONS---
export const doGoogleLoginAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN
  });
  return loginWithGoogle() //this is the function defined in firebase.js which lets me do the google Login and returns a promise
    .then(user => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: { ...user } //we send a new copy of user
      });
      saveStorage(getState());
    })
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, payload: err.message }));
}; //it returns the data from the user

//---UTILS---
const saveStorage = storage => {
  //we save the state in the localstorage
  localStorage.storage = JSON.stringify(storage);
};
```

here is my component LoginPage.js:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./login.module.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { doGoogleLoginAction } from "../../redux/userReducer";

function LoginPage(fetching, googleLogin) {
    
  function doLogin() {
    googleLogin();
  }

//   if (fetching) return <h2>Loading</h2>;

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Inicia Sesión con Google</h1>
      <h1>Cierra tu sesión</h1>
      <button onClick={doLogin}>Iniciar</button>
      <button>Cerrar Sesión</button>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ user: { fetching } }) => {
  //we take the state.user.fetching from the store and we return it
  return { fetching };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  googleLogin: doGoogleLoginAction
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

and the output:

```
LoginPage.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: googleLogin is not a function
    at doLogin (LoginPage.js:9)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:454)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:584)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:609)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:713)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:722)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:694)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:739)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:880)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5803)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24401)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1415)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:5894)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6010)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5914)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12149)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24417)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1438)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5881)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to destructure your props

```
function LoginPage({ fetching, googleLogin }) {
```

You get first argument called props from which you need stuff.

Answer (score 0):

all methods and state in redux will be used in component as props.

```
this.props.googleLogin()
```

Comment: sorry but what would userActions be??? I do not get it, it does not work neither  it says the module it is not found

Comment: you have actions and reducers in one file ?